WPF loading animation with video
I am trying to use a video as a loading animation. I am using a MediaPlayer to play the video and a behavior that starts and stops the video, when the visibility of the view is set to collapse. But this method really has an impact on the performance and I think stopping the video is not enough to increase it. I see that many use spinners with a storyboard, but this animation is more complex so would love to be able to use it. Also methods decreasing the framerate like formatting it to a gif are not that suitable because it is very smooth.
    <Border x:Name="LoadingScreenBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:MediaPlayerBehavior VideoSource="resources\animation\loadinganimationroundwhite.wmv" PlaceholderImage="Resources\Animation\PlaceholderImage\LoadingAnimationRoundWhitePlaceholder.png"></b:MediaPlayerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Border>

        private void OnParentIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is FrameworkElement parentElement)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine($"Parent visibility changed to: {parentElement.Visibility}");
                if (parentElement.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Calling StopLoadingScreen from parent visibility change");
                    StopLoadingScreen();
                }
                else if(parentElement.Visibility == Visibility.Visible && parentElement.IsLoaded == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Calling StartLoadingScreen from parent visibility change");
                    StartLoadingScreen();
                }
            }
        }


        private void StartLoadingScreen()
        {
            if (VideoSource != null)
            {
                _mediaPlayer.Open(VideoSource);
            }
        }

        private void StopLoadingScreen()
        {
            _mediaPlayer.Stop();
            _mediaPlayer.Close();
            if (_placeholderBrush != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.Background = _placeholderBrush;
            }
            else
            {

                AssociatedObject.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent);
            }
        }

Tried using a mediaelement with pretty much the same functionallity, like stopping it when the view is set to collapsed and to close the mediaelement. I am thankfull for every help!

Instead of toggling visibility consider adding to/removing from visual tree. Make behavior which adds control to ContentControl.Content or sets it back to null.

Use a "second window" for the animation. (I can run 3 instances of my "4 element" WPF queued video viewer while in VS with a different app and watching NetFlix. Ryzen 7)
